# How can I get the mean of 5 tensors along an axis?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 5 tensors of shape `torch.Size([7, 20, 180])`

I want to get the mean of each along `dim=1` so that my final shape will be `torch.Size([7, 20, 180])`.

Basically, I want the first element from the first tensor, then the first element from the second tensor, and so on to be averaged.

Comment: I guess the result dimension should be `(7,180)`; have you tried `x.mean(dim=1)` for each tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention how these 5 tensors are stored, but let's assume they are in a list. Here's a way to do it:

```py
import torch

x = [torch.rand((7, 20, 180)) for _ in range(5)]
y = torch.stack(x).mean(dim=0)

print(y.shape)
# >>> torch.Size([7, 20, 180])
```

I'm also assuming you said `dim=1` as if PyTorch was 1-based indexing, which it is not.

---

<sub>I see you are asking many questions recently, which is not a problem. I've said this once, but again: always try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is always good to show some effort as well. Have you tried anything before asking?</sub>